# Error while making object persistent

Tags: google-app-engine, persistence, vaadin, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm trying to write a Vaadin application on GAE platform with using JDO, and when I want to call this method:

```
public void createUser(String login, String password, String email) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    User user = new User(login, password, email);
    try {
        pm.makePersistent(user);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }

}
```

I get this error:

> (...)Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
>   NestedThrowables:
>   javax.jdo.JDOUserException: You have either specified for this PMF to use a "persistence-unit" of "transactions-optional" (yet this doesnt exist!) or you called JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory with "transactions-optional" as the name of a properties file (and this doesnt exist in the CLASSPATH)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:856)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1092)
>       at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:914)
>       at myapp.PMF.(PMF.java:8)
>       ... 43 more
>   Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOUserException: You have either specified for this PMF to use a "persistence-unit" of "transactions-optional" (yet this doesnt exist!) or you called JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory with "transactions-optional" as the name of a properties file (and this doesnt exist in the CLASSPATH) (...)

I've searched the Google and found some solutions for this problem, but none works for my app (or I'm doing something incorrectly).
For eg.[this](http://jasonsmart.wordpress.com/) wouldn't work. Oh, and I have the jdoconfig.xml file in META-INF.
If anyone had similar problem, and he'd like to share his wisdom I would be very appreciate.

EDIT: jdoconfig file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">
    <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
            value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite"
            value="true" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns"
            value="true" />
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

Comment: and you haven't told us about your jdoconfig.xml or persistence.xml file, and where they are located

Comment: I've told: I have the jdoconfig.xml file in META-INF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it!

> jdoconfig.xml

file was in

> \war\META-INF

directory that Eclipse had created. Should be in

> \war\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF

Dumb mistake...

Comment: where is this war directory??  Ive been looking for a solution for a while and don't see this war directory in my app nor in my endpoints directory

Comment: actually in your project you need to create 'classes' subfolder under 'WEB-INF' and the 'META-INF' subfolder under 'classes'. That is not a dumb mistake, from GAE tutorial I have wrongly got that I need to create META-INF folder on the same level as WEB-IF (as it works in the majority of all web projects, but not here with JDO's jdoconf.xml).